# Up Arrow Sometimes Moves Up Two Spaces in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I recently setup my dev environment on a new computer, and I'm having a very odd issue where pressing the up arrow sometimes moves my cursor up two spaces instead of one. I haven't been able to spot a pattern to when it happens, and it's really frustrating. Has anyone experienced anything similar? Here's my .emacs, in case it helps:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")                             

(unless (require 'el-get nil t)                                                 
  (url-retrieve                                                                 
   "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el"             
   (lambda (s)                                                                  
     (end-of-buffer)                                                            
     (eval-print-last-sexp))))                                                  

(delete-trailing-whitespace)                                                   
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/")                                   
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/js2-mode")                           
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/pig-mode")                           
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/fill-column-indicator")              
(autoload 'js2-mode "js2-mode" nil t)                                           
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js$" . js2-mode))                           
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pig$" . pig-mode))                          
(require 'whitespace)                                                           
(require 'pig-mode)                                                             
(require 'fill-column-indicator)                                                
`(require 'color-theme-zenburn)`                                               
`(color-theme-zenburn)`                                                         
(setq scroll-step            1                                                  
      scroll-conservatively  10000)                                             
(setq column-number-mode t)                                                     

(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes")              
(el-get 'sync)                                                                  

(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")              
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")  
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))     
(setq-default fill-column 80)                                                   
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'fci-mode)                              

;;Whitespace stuff                                                              

; make carriage returns blue and tabs green                                     
(custom-set-faces                                                               
 '(my-carriage-return-face ((((class color)) (:background "blue"))) t)          
 '(my-tab-face ((((class color)) (:background "green"))) t)                     
 )
; add custom font locks to all buffers and all files                            
(add-hook                                                                       
 'font-lock-mode-hook                                                           
 (function                                                                      
  (lambda ()                                                                    
    (setq                                                                       
     font-lock-keywords                                                         
     (append                                                                    
      font-lock-keywords                                                        
      '(                                                                        
    ("\r" (0 'my-carriage-return-face t))                                   
    ("\t" (0 'my-tab-face t))                                               
        ))))))                                                                  

; transform literal tabs into a right-pointing triangle                         
(setq                                                                           
 whitespace-display-mappings ;http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/whitespace-mode.html   
 '(                                                                             
   (tab-mark 9 [9654 9] [92 9])                                                 
   ;others substitutions...                                                     
   ))
```

Comment: Are you certain it's not a hardware problem?

Comment: Yes. Problem is only in emacs.

Comment: How frequently does it happen? All I can really suggest offhand is the typical approach to hunting down problems without a known source -- using vanilla (`emacs -Q`) for a while to find out whether config has anything to do with it. If that's free from the problem, repeat with `emacs -q` to introduce system libraries. If that then narrows it down to your own config, then use a binary search pattern with your custom packages and libraries.

Comment: There *are* strange things in your init file, mind. `(delete-trailing-whitespace)` probably doesn't do what you want it to do, and the following code will do nothing at all, due to the bizarre usage of the backquotes: `\`(require 'color-theme-zenburn)\`
\`(color-theme-zenburn)\`
(setq scroll-step 1 scroll-conservatively  10000)`

Comment: Could it be [this](https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator/issues/31)?

Comment: @Biffen yeah, it looks like turning off the fill-column-indicator fixes things. Thanks! If you add that as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator/issues/31) with [`fci-mode`](https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator) in combination with Emacs v24.3 (or with Emacs, depending on who you ask).